# как исключить элемент из поиска?

Tags: jquery

У меня есть поиск элементов. Блок, в котором происходит поиск значений состоит из нескольких элементов. Мне нужно исключить последний элемент из поиска. Т.е. что бы данный элемент не затрагивался, кроме остальных. Пробовал вот так

```
$('.blog_content_item').not('.last').each(function() {...});
```

и так

```
$(".blog_content_item:not('.last')").each(function() {...});
```

Не помогает. И то, и то не верно по синтаксису. Подскажите пожалуйста, как из поиска исключить элемент "last". Спасибо.

```js
$('.blog_content_item').each(function() {
  if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1) {
  ...
  return;
  } else {
  ...
         }             
});
```

```html
<div class="blog_content_item">
  <div class="first">
  <div class="middle">
  <div class="last">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во первых, пробуете вы применить `:not` к самому `.blog-..` хотя нужно к его потомкам. Во вторых, `.last` включаете в кавычки, отсюда и ошибка синтаксиса, видимо.

```
$(".blog-content-item > div:not(.last)").each(....)
```

либо

```
$(".blog").children().not(".last")
```

и т.п. вариации

в целом эти классы вы можете заменить на `:last-child`